Which materials illuminate when hit by a laser beam?
I have a laser that I mounted to the ceiling of my garage to use as a parking assist. The laser has a maximum power output of 1mW at 635-670nm. I am searching for some material that I can mount on the dashboard of a vehicle that will receive the laser beam and glow or illuminate, but not reflect.
I have considered acquiring a circle of ground glass, or dome of frosted glass. I have also considered that some phosphorescent material could be used.
I have played with some transparent plastics and non-frosted glass. The light tends to escape and the reflected light could potential end up in someones eye.
I have also tried some translucent plastics with varied results. I tried a rubbery material (unsure of the composition) that glowed somewhat, but was a bit too opaque.

cut a piece from a plastic milk jug

This is taking hanging a tennis ball from a string to a whole new level

I'm not sure if you'll find what you're looking for. As far as I know, fluorescent materials always emit light of longer wavelength than that of the excitation (as they emit lower energy photons than those of the excitation). Since you're using a red light laser, that means any fluorescence, if a suitable material could be found, would be moving towards infrared rather than towards blue.
Reading material:

Fluorescence Excitation and Emission Fundamentals

Science Direct - Long-wavelength fluorophores: new trends in their analytical use.

Wikipedia - Fluorescence.



URANIUM GLASS absorb laser light and re-emit it, causing them to glow. Fluorescent markers used in labs are designed for this purpose.

"... absorb laser light ..." of what wavelength? The OP is using 635-670 nm.
